# AVAudioSession: Record audio in app while simultaneously allowing Music app to play over bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, audio-recording, avaudiosession

I've been having trouble getting an app to record audio while simultaneously letting the iPhone music app play over bluetooth speakers.

For example if I do this:

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&error];

session setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Then Music app will start playing music through the iPhone built in speaker instead of over bluetooth. In other words there appears to be no way to record audio in an app and still allow Music to play over bluetooth.

If I remove AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker , then the audio route will switch to the receiver. Which is worse than having it come through the iPhone speaker. Then I can set `[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];` to force output back to the speaker, but this does not solve the bluetooth issue. Output will now be on the speaker just as with AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker.

How can I record audio and not interfere with playback over bluetooth from other apps (especially the Music app)?

Comment: find any solutions???

Answer (score 0):

You think you have to add `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` to your AVSession `setCategory:` to allow the bluetooth use.

Beside that, the microphone selected for recording will be the one set in the AVSession's `[[currentRoute inputs] firstObject]`. You should probably check it/change it accordingly if your bluetooth device have a microphone?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I previously tried the allow bluetooth setting and that caused bluetooth music to stop as well, but I did not set the microphone as you suggest.

Comment: Note, I was in car previously which does have a microphone and it looked like app was trying to use that. I'll try now using the setPrefferredInput to be the builtInMic.